# Pagination with Kaminari, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

I have a trouble with pagination with gem Kaminari!

For example, I have 18 pages,per_page for pagination - 10 pages.when I located at first link, i see 5 links. When located at 4 - 8 links to pages, at 7 - 10. I need to showing 10 pages always, although if I located at first or last page(if I have 10 and more pages). If i have 7 pages - I must see 7 links on first pages. 
Any proposition?

Comment: use 'will-paginate' :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell - I use Will-paginate for pagination and Kaminari for customize views.

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight forward way of doing this. One option will be setting the window size, ie the number of pages to show after and before the current page.

```
<%= paginate @listings, :window => 3 %>
```

You can generate the window size based on the current page and send it to the paginate call.

Comment: Its not good example.If my current page is first page, then I see active first link, and three links after it. If my current page is fifth page, then I see active fifth link, three links after it and three links defore it. But I need to see on fisrt page ten links, on second page ten links, on third also ten etc.

Comment: There is no straight forward way to do it. You can configure the number of links on the left/right together(window size). But there is no way to configure and show n number of link always.